# Questions about pets / terrarium overflow

Tags: support, site-recommendation

On which sub-site should I ask questions on aquaterrarium construction?

Is there a pet-"overflow" that allows question about terrarium/aquarium construction and not just pet handling?

Is the DIY sub site suitable otherwise ?

Comment: There is a proposal on Area 51: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/44686/pets .

Comment: Terrarium Overflow? Put in a sensor to stop the water filling up when it reaches the top! ;)

Answer (score 11):

There is a [Pets](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/44686/pets) Stack Exchange site that is about to go into beta phase. I think it would suit your needs.

The Pets beta hasn't started yet, but you can commit to the site (click on the Commit!) button in the link, and you will get a private invitation as soon as the beta begins.

Note: Your question would be off topic on DIY site.

Comment: Argh... Private beta for 6 more days, no commitments allowed at this time. Guess I'll have to wait a week.

Comment: @BlakBat Yeah you just missed it, private beta literally just started about 5 hrs after you posted and it was accepting commits up til then. Hold on to your question until public beta I guess :)